# EXCEL I need the easiest way to copy Data in the form of barcodes from one column the the next column in plain text

Tags: excel

As the title says I need the quickest way to automatically copy information/data from column A3:A23 to columns B3:B23. I am not that great in excel and looked for an answer but couldn't get anything to work! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using VBA? Can you add some sample data to your post? A little bit more detail will help us answer your question.

Comment: I think there is no such way of selecting "quickly". Select, the required columns `B3:B23` with "mouse" and right-click on `B3` and paste special. Alternatively, you can press `W`, after you hover on `paste special`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```
sub test()
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = sheets("yoursheetname")

ws.range(ws.cells(3, 2), ws.cells(23,2)).value = ws.range(ws.cells(3, 1), ws.cells(23,1)).value

end sub
```